# Service worker not working in electron but works great in browser

Tags: electron, create-react-app, service-worker

In my react application have a service worker working in the browser as expected. Unfortunately when the application is built and packaged with electron the service worker does not work. It seems to register but the service worker throws a error - `uncaught in promise typeerror failed to fetch`

The only real difference I can see is the origin of the worker. In electron it is stating a file path where as the one in the browser is stating the http://localhost path. This is using electron 11. The application is written in react from create-react app which has not been ejected.

Answer (score 0):

This error originates from **CORS**(Cross Origin Resource Sharing). The thing is if you delete your service worker content and leave maybe a simple console.log statement the app would work. That is because in your fetch handler in service worker you are manually sending requests with Fetch API.
Unfortunately, CORS rules which are set inside your application are lost inside your service worker if you use the Fetch API.
If you really want to have that fetch handler in your service worker you have two choices:

1. You can customize the fetch handler so it doesn't do anything for index.html(which is the most important file for you). In that case if you don't do anything and you don't use event.respondWith, the request will not be stopped by service worker and your CORS headers will not be lost.
2. This is the tougher option. You need to set your CORS headers manually in the service worker fetch handler.